# npm install PATH for postinstall scripts on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, npm-install, commitizen

My JS project uses a NPM package called `commitizen`:
https://github.com/commitizen/cz-cli

`commitizen` is added to my `devDependencies` in package.json file.
`commitizen` uses internally a package called `opencollective` as you can see here: https://github.com/commitizen/cz-cli/blob/master/package.json

`commitizen` on postinstall hook is calling `opencollective postinstall` which is supposed to run `opencollective` package binary.

Locally I've no problems running the postinstall hook, however, when I build my project on my Jenkins CI box I get this error when it runs the postinstall hook of `commitizen` package

```
sh: 1: opencollective: not found

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! commitizen@2.10.1 postinstall: `opencollective postinstall`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the commitizen@2.10.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I tried to add *`node_modules/opencollective/dist/bin`* dir to the PATH but with no luck, I think because the `opencollective` alias is defined in `opencollective` package.json

Any idea about how to be able to run opencollective command without installing globally `opencollective` package?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you installed *commitizen* globally?

Comment: please check a file named `opencollective` exists in `node_modules/.bin`, if not, means the npm package opencollective install failed.  then when commitizen call `opencollective postinstall`, it can't find `opencollective` from `node_modules/.bin`.  If so, you can install `opencollective` in advance by run `npm i opencollective`  under project folder to check it can be install successfully, then run `npm install`

Comment: It can't be installed globally since it's a Ci machine and I don't have control over it

Comment: @yong Thanks for your comment. I've checked and there is an `opencollective` alias in `node_modules/.bin` directory. So what was missing is to tell Jenkins to add that directoty to PATH. That can be done by simply adding the following `:${env.WORKSPACE}/node_modules/.bin` to PATH configuration in `Jenkinsfile` file

Comment: @gabric, I think we no need to append `${env.WORKSPACE}/node_modules/.bin` too `PATH`,  i can install `commitizen` successfully on my Mac with out appending it to `PATH`.  Could you show the  shell used to install packages for project  in your jenkins job